# Twitter Advanced Search Results Are Unevenly Distributed by Year

Tags: python, twitter

I'm using the twitter browser search function to surpass the api's one week limit and gather historical tweets for research purposes. I'm using the github repository found here: https://github.com/Jefferson-Henrique/GetOldTweets-python
This all worked very nicely, but with one rather odd hitch. I was gathering tweets within a 300 mile radius of Delhi with certain keywords from 1/1/2013 to 6/15/2017, and although I get tweets for all 4.5 years, there are always significantly more from around Dec 2013 to Apr 2015, no matter what the keyword or location is. I scoured the web to see if twitter made some sort of change to how it stores tweets, but found no plausible explanation, which led me here. 
Here's a code snippet (I can provide more, or output files if needed):

```
wordsearch("headache", 0, "en", "40.7128,-74.0059", "2015-01-01", "headacheNYC2015", "300mi")
```

Also, it's not due to 3rd party sources, as those are included. There is also a notable lack of retweets. I am aware that the search function only provides a random 1% sample, but this is a separate issue as there are never as many tweets after April 2015. 
If anyone knows ANY possible reason for this, please share!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the answer. In 2015 Twitter changed the way geotags worked, they added the preference/set default preference for geotagging tweets turned off. Thus when searching for geotagged tweets, there are far less after this point. More details can be found [here](https://twittercommunity.com/t/twitter-search-api-always-return-geo-null/66166/2)